# Solving for Floquet multipliers: solving over multiple periods

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, periodic-functions, stability-in-odes, delay-differential-equations

Everywhere that I've read about performing a Floquet analysis involves numerically solving the system over one period, with the identity matrix as initial condition. My system is fairly complex, has multiple delays, and has long transient dynamics before reaching equilibrium. My problem is that the **results of the Floquet analysis do not correspond to the results of a long simulation** (i.e., the asymptotic solution to the initial value problem shows a different equilibrium point than suggested by the leading Floquet exponent). If I perform the Floquet analysis, numerically solving the system over, say, 10 periods or more, then the result converges with the simulation. I haven't been able to find any examples of someone that's done this, or anywhere that says this is valid. **Is this a violation of the method?** I'd also like to know if this raises red flags that maybe I've made a mistake in my model or code somewhere, although I've checked it thoroughly.

I've implemented the numerical routine described in Lemma 2.5 in the following paper, which was adapted for DDEs:

- [Liang, X., Zhang, L. & Zhao, XQ. Basic Reproduction Ratios for Periodic Abstract Functional Differential Equations (with Application to a Spatial Model for Lyme Disease). *J Dyn Diff Equat* **31**, 1247–1278 (2019).](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10884-017-9601-7):

> **Lemma 2.5** Assume that (E, E<sub>+</sub>) is an ordered Banach space with E<sub>+</sub> being normal and Int(E<sub>+</sub>) $\neq$ ∅,
> which is equipped with the norm ||·||<sub>E</sub> . Let L be a
> positive bounded linear operator. Choose v<sub>0</sub> ∈
> Int(E<sub>+</sub>) and define a<sub>n</sub> =
> ||Lv<sub>n-1</sub>||<sub>E</sub> , v<sub>n</sub> = $\frac{Lv_{n-1}}{
> > a_{n}}$, ∀n ≥ 1. If $\lim_{(n→+∞)}a_n$ exists, then r(L) =
> $\lim_{n→+∞}a_n$.

The leading Floquet exponent is then calculated as $\mu$ = $\frac{log(r(L))}{\omega}$, where $\omega$ = the period (i.e., 1 year)

Comment: Why are you optimistic that Floquet analysis applies to DDE? The initial history would have to match the periodic pattern, thus it is not that astonishing that you get better results if you let the dynamic stabilize. Did you try to find the exponents from just the last of the 10 periods of integration?

Comment: @LutzLehmann I edited the post to include the algorithm I'm using, which was developed for DDEs. I tried your suggestion of using just the last period of integration but it didn't fix the problem. The problem seems to be that the system takes several periods to begin growing and if it is only allowed to evolve over a single period in each iteration the algorithm does not "see" this delayed growth. To me it seems like it would be okay to solve over multiple periods rather than just one, but then maybe the exponents would have to be interpreted slightly differently (e.g. different units).

Comment: You are applying the power iteration method to an operator on the infinite-dimensional space $E_+$. In the current case this space contains the history function, or rather its perturbations around a periodic solution. As such it contains a space of continuous functions, is thus at least countably infinite. In general, the propagation operator for these perturbations will not be "almost finite", so convergence will be very slow, if it happens at all.